# Why border texels get the same color when magnified/scaled up using Bilinear filtering?

Tags: opengl, shader

As in Bilinear filtering, sampled color is calculated based on the weighted average of 4 closest texels, then why corner texels get the same color when magnified?

Eg:

In this case (image below) when a 3x3 image is magnified/scaled to 5x5 pixel image (using Bilinear filtering) corner 'Red' pixels get exact same color and border 'Green' as well?

[image: 3x3 pixel to 5x5 pixel scaling]

In some documents, it is explained that corner texels are extended with the same color to give 4 adjacent texels which explains why corner 'Red' texels are getting the same color in 5x5 image but how come border 'Green' texels are getting same color (if they are calculated based on weighted average of 4 closest texels)

Answer (score 6):

When you are using bilinear texture sampling, the texels in the texture are not treated as colored squares but as samples of a continuous color field. Here is this field for a red-green checkerboard, where the texture border is outlined:

[image: Continuous Color Field]

The circles represent the texels, i.e., the sample locations of the texture. The colors between the samples are calculated by bilinear interpolation. As a special case, the interpolation between two adjacent texels is a simple linear interpolation. When `x` is between `0` and `1`, then: `color = (1 - x) * leftColor + x * rightColor`.

The interpolation scheme only defines what happens in the area between the samples, i.e. not even up to the edge of the texture. What OpenGL uses to determine the missing area is the texture's or sampler's wrap mode. If you use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, the texel values from the edge will just be repeated like in the example above. With this, we have defined the color field for arbitrary texture coordinates.

Now, when we render a 5x5 image, the fragments' colors are evaluated at the pixel centers. This looks like the following picture, where the fragment evaluation positions are marked with black dots:

[image: Fragment Evaluation Positions]

Assuming that you draw a full-screen quad with texture coordinates ranging from 0 to 1, the texture coordinates at the fragment evaluation positions are interpolations of the vertices' texture coordinates. We can now just overlay the color field from before with the fragments and we will find the color that the bilinear sampler produces:

[image: Color Field and Fragment Positions]

We can see a couple of things:

1. The central fragment coincides exactly with the red texel and therefore gets a perfect red color.
2. The central fragments on the edges fall exactly between two green samples (where one sample is a virtual sample outside of the texture). Therefore, they get a perfect green color. This is due to the wrap mode. Other wrap modes produce different colors. The interpolation is then: `color = (1 - t) * outsideColor + t * insideColor`, where `t = 3 * (0.5 / 5 + 0.5 / 3) = 0.8` is the interpolation parameter.
3. The corner fragments are also interpolations from four texel colors (1 real inside the texture and three virtual outside). Again, due to the wrap mode, these will get a perfect red color.
4. All other colors are some interpolation of red and green.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at bilinear interpolation incorrectly. Look at it as a mapping from the destination pixel position to the source pixel position. So for each desintation pixel, there is a source coordinate that corresponds to it. This source coordinate is what determines the 4 neighboring pixels, as well as the bilinear weights assigned to them.

Let us number your pixels with (0, 0) at the top left.

Pixel (0, 0) in the destination image maps to the coordinate (0, 0) in the source image. The four neighboring pixels in the source image are (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1) and (1, 1). We compute the bilinear weights with simple math: the weight in the X direction for a particular pixel is `1 - (pixel.x - source.x)`, where `source` is the source coordinate. The same goes for Y. So the bilinear weights for each of the four neighboring pixels are (respective to the above order): (1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0) and (0, 0).

In short, because the destination pixel mapped *exactly* to a source pixel, it gets exactly that source pixel's value. This is as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure this is accurate? The texture coordinates of the lower corner fragment would be `(0.5 / 5, 0.5 / 5) = (0.1, 0.1)` (fragments are sampled at the pixel center). This texture coordinate does not coincide with a texel location (the nearest would be `(0.5 / 3, 0.5 / 3) = (0.166, 0.166)`). Hence, the sampled color is actually an interpolation of the corner texel and three texels outside the texture. And then it is up to the clamping settings. I tried to check the math, but there seems to be some tone-mapping in the image. The brown color is not a straight interpolation of red and green.

Comment: Nico, yes that's the calculation I am using and that is why I am confused that why border "Green" texels are full green. At least 2 of its neighboring texels should be "Red"?

Comment: @user2259784 The green texels are somewhat more apparent. Their sampling coordinate lies exactly between two texels (one component is 0.5). And if your clamping mode is either repeat or clamp, this is an interpolation between green and green. I am more confused about the red corner pixels. What is your clamping mode, btw? If it is clamp, then this is your answer.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, can you please explain how the texel color is calculated (based on weighted average of 4 texels) when sampling coordinate lies exactly between two texels?
And the image is in clamp mode

Comment: @NicoSchertler: "*The texture coordinates*" I never called anything a texture coordinate. I said we would be *numbering* pixels, not *normalizing* them.

Comment: Hm.. I see. How do you define the mapping then? In my understanding, most destination pixels are not mapped to source pixels.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: That's why the source pixel location for the destination pixel at (1, 0) is (0.5, 0). Halfway between source pixels (0, 0) and (1, 0).